# 500 Internal Error on jQuery Web Method Call - IIS 5.1 ( :-/ yea i know...)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod, iis-5

i can't figure out what i'm missing, is there an IIS Setting that needs to be changed, possibly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function AjaxSuccess(result) {

        alert('result: ' + result);
    }

    function AjaxError(result) {
        alert("error");
        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }


    $(".hlp").click(function () {
        var myVal= $(this).val();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxWebMethods.aspx/GetHelpText",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'helpText' : '" + id + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: AjaxSuccess,
            error: AjaxError
        });
    });

});
```

my web method is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class AjaxWebMethods : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ }

    #region Exposed WebMethods
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public string GetHelpText(string helpItem)
    {
        string helpText = "testing web method";
        return helpText;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

i keep getting 2 pop ups 
"error"
and then the 501 error.
please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change this line  `data: "{'id' : '" + id + "'}",` to  `data: "{'helpItem' : '" + id + "'}",`

as webmethod is taking `helpItem` as parameter name.

so ajax function finally wil be

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxWebMethods.aspx/GetHelpText",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'helpItem' : '" + id + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: AjaxSuccess,
            error: AjaxError
        });
```

and make your serverside method static like this

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static string GetHelpText(string helpItem)
    {
```

Check the article help you for this : [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html)

Comment: Thank you! Updated, but still getting the same thing :(

Answer (score 3):

Your data is `id` and your Web Method is expecting `helpItem`.  Try aligning the two.

`data: "{helpItem: '" + id + "'}"`

Another thing to try is to add `static` to your WebMethod declaration.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string GetHelpText(int helpItem)
{
```

Comment: thank you! it was a combination of yours and Pranay's responses! it's working now :)